# How to write Key Value Pairs in Map in a Loop without overwriting them?

Tags: dictionary, arraylist, groovy

the following is my problem:
I do a select on my database and want to write the values of every record i get in a map. When i do this, i only have the values of one record in my map, because the put() function overwrites the entries everytime the loop starts again. Since I have to transfer the Key:Value pairs via JSON into my Javascript and write something into a field for every Key:Value pair, an ArrayList is not an option.

I've already tried to convert a ArrayList, which contains the Map, to a Map or to a String and then to Map, but i failed.

**EDIT:**
Here´s my Code

```
def valueArray = new ArrayList();
def recordValues = [:]
while (rs.next())
        {
            fremdlKorr = rs.getFloatValue(1)
            leistungKorr = rs.getFloatValue(2)
            materialKorr = rs.getFloatValue(3)
            strid = rs.getStringValue(4)

            recordValues.put("strid", strid);
            recordValues.put("material", materialKorr);
            recordValues.put("fremdl", fremdlKorr);
            recordValues.put("leistung", leistungKorr);

            valueArray.add(korrekturWerte);
        }
```

The ArrayList was just a test, i dont want to have an ArrayList, i need a Map.

Comment: You want a list of maps. But without a simple example of what you're trying, it's impossible to accurately help more

Comment: No, i dont want a list of maps, because i need to do a each loop for every key:value pair. With a list i can't do that, so i need a map. But when i put the Key:Value pairs in my map, they get overwritten everytime the select finds a record matching my criteria. I will post my code in a minute

Comment: so you still get a list of maps. If you really need a map for whatever reason, you can key it by record ids, to avoid overwriting

Comment: @kjell0w, show how would you like to access the result to access rows/columns.

Comment: Please provide sample input (e.g. two rows from your select) and what output you expect from that.  Also note, that if you use Groovy's Sql, you get maps directly, so you dont have to do the jdbc dance. http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html

Comment: Also `s/korrekturWerte/recordValues` ?

Answer (score 2):

The code as written, will give you a list of maps, but the maps will all contain the values of the last row.  The reaons is the `def recordValues = [:]` that is *outside* of the while loop.  So you basically add always the same map to the list and the map values get overwritten each loop.

While moving the code, would fix the problem, I'd use [Sql](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html) instead.  That all boils down to:

```
def valueArray = sql.rows("select strid, material, fremdl, leistung from ...")
```